# Jordan Visa on arrival for Indian National with Jordan Pass

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, visas-on-arrival, jordan

How stringent are the rules regarding 1000USD pp in order to get VoA?

we are a group of 12 on a budget travel, and frankly there is no way we will be carrying 12,000 USD in cash. Apart from being expensive, the risk of losing physical cash to something unfortunate is too much.

All other threads online are 3-4 years old where Indians were being harassed by immigration officers regarding the cash rule. How is the situation now?

We are planning to carry return tickets, prepaid hotel bookings, rental car bookings, jordan pass and about 2000USD for the group as liquid cash, planning to withdraw as and when required.

Anybody suggests meet and greet at airport? those services too seem to be ridiculously expensive. (top few search results on google - didn't research much)

Answer (score 2):

This question is difficult to answer as it sometimes purely depends on the judgement of individual custom officers.

I would strongly advise you to discuss this matter with the Jordan embassy in India. Here you can talk to an official representative of Jordan in person or via telephone. He can tell you what you should do and maybe provide you with a writing that would have you bypass the rule.